# How to use import an existing Database into a Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 project in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I am doing a project in which it has been imposed that I must use Netbeans 6.9.1 and Rails 2.3.8. The operating system must be Windows and we are not allowed to use the command line. We are required to use a MySQL Database (already created and fully functional) and we must import the tables from the database into models, view, and controllers in the Rails project. I don't know how we're supposed to do this because the way Rails works implies that you use the application to make the database, but we have to use the database to make the application.

I've put several dozen of hours into looking this up but I've come up empty handed because every tutorial I found for Rails either uses the command line, or uses scaffolding to create tables to put in the database instead of vice versa.

The question is, how can I generate models, views, controllers, etc. from existing database tables using only the tools in Netbeans? I'm new to both Rails and Ruby so coding them all manually would be extremely difficult because all the routes go funny. If anyone has a solution it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Rails works by imposing strict conventions on naming. Read the guides or the apis, learn the conventions, then figure out how you have to name things. I don't see how Netbeans is relevant here, but I guess you have to use it to look at the table schema.

Comment: Netbeans is relevant because they are enforcing the sole use of it. I have seen a lot of potentially useful commands but have been unable to use them because of our Windows/Netbeans configuration. Also, I have read through the guides. I was unable to find something that makes sense in our situation.